# Is it possible to specify a minimum fold level?

Tags: vim, folding

In my javascript code I am wrapping everything into one anonymous function. When I use folding in vim *everything* is folded, which is quite useless. I want to fold for example only the second level, while keeping the first level expanded (preferably still with syntax folding). How can I achieve this in vim?

```
(function(gobj) {
    function fun1() {
        ...
    }
    function fun2() {
        ...
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems before, when using vim and javascript.

This plugin solved most of my problems (auto-indentation, syntax folding, syntax highlighting, ...)

vim-javascript  https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-javascript

Comment: Are you using :set foldmethod=syntax?

Comment: Looks like I had a wrong setting for `foldnestmax`, it works now.